# IE8 not supporting Google Charts (Pie Chart)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, pie-chart, google-visualization

IE8 is not rendering Google Charts (Pie Charts).

It is giving me an error saying : 
SCRIPT5: Type mismatch: jsapi, line 20 character 89

I have tried looking on the web for a solution, tried all of them, but to no use.

I am debugging my application using IE Developer tool, with the following setting:

1. Browser Mode : IE8
2. Document Mode: IE standards.

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Did anyone face the same problem? I am not even able to run the standard example code given by Google on IE8 with the same configurations mentioned above. 
It just does not display anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a problem with the emulator (and google charts) in IE9+, I am right now trying to get a standalone IE8 running in a VM to try it on but I've seen reports here that **it works when you are actually using IE8**.

Comment: Thanks F. Aquino.
I observed the same thing, there does seem to be a problem with IE9+ emulator and google charts. It does work with actual IE8.