# Nowrap condition in html head and body

Tags: jquery, html, css

In jsfiddle they have option to set `no wrap(head)`, `no wrap(body)`, `OnDomReady` and `OnLoad` in left side option. In my program to set `no wrap(head)` condition. Its work fine. But how I change in to HTML file. The same condition I need to set in my HTML file

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3KxFZ/2/)

Here I set `no-wrap(head)`, How I set HTML file the same condition as `no-wrap(head)`?.

Here my full code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['Russia', 700]
]);

// this chart is drawn in a visible div and then immediately hidden
var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_1'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
    // hide the div when done drawing
    document.getElementById('chart_1').style.display = 'none';

    // create an event listener for the button that shows the chart
    document.getElementById('clickMe1').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('chart_1').style.display = 'block';
    }
});

// show the div before you draw
document.getElementById('chart_1').style.display = 'block';

chart1.draw(data, {
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Chart 1'
});


// this chart only gets drawn when the button is clicked
var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_2'));

// create an event listener for the button that shows the chart
document.getElementById('clickMe2').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('chart_2').style.display = 'block';
    chart2.draw(data, {
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        title: 'Chart 2'
    });               
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#visualization path {
cursor: pointer
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
<input type="button" value="Show chart 1" id="clickMe1" />
<input type="button" value="Show chart 2" id="clickMe2" />
<div id="chart_1" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="chart_2" style="display: none"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That simply means place your JavaScript between the `<head>` tags

From the documentation page

[image: JSFiddle Documentation]

[Reference](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html)

Comment: Hi, I update my html code here. In my code all my javascript are placed inside the head tag. But why its not work?

Comment: You are missing a close `script` tag on this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">script>`

Comment: ho, This error causes while I am pasting the code here. Can you tell why its not working?

Comment: may in know, this code work in ie8 document mode in your machine.?

Comment: @Selva No, I can't see the pie using nowrap head as well as nowrap body

Comment: Thanks you. But here present the same code http://jsfiddle.net/3KxFZ/2/ . Its work IE8 document mode in `no-wrap(head)` condition. It shows. May I know Why its not working the html file, may did any wrong thing in that file.

Comment: I don't see any real issue with the file unless and until jquery source issue but that's not applicable here too :) and still it doesn't work for me, am using compatibility mode to check

Answer (score 3):

It just means that the script is added in the `<head>` section of the `<html>`

From [**JSFiddle Docs**](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar),

> no wrap(head): do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<head>`
>   section

**[Here](http://jsbin.com/azumag/3/edit)** is a demo of what you might be using (All HTML at one place).

Comment: Thank you, may in know, this code work in ie8 document mode in your machine.? If not how may i correct it, Because that fiddle work in IE8 document mode.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but I remember that this is because google charts have some problems with `IE8` document mode, [**Check this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081894/ie8-not-supporting-google-charts-pie-chart)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3KxFZ/2/ but here the second piechart visible in ie8 document mode, How?

Comment: Nope, both not working for me on `IE8`. This has to do something with Google pie chart incompatibility with IE8. The examples mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), themselves do **NOT** work on IE8 emulator mode. And it seems to have [effects](http://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Pie+chart+not+showing+in+IE8) on a lot of devs.