# setInterval() example from the Javascript Mozilla docs not working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript

I copied over Example #2 given in the Mozilla docs about setInterval() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval#Example_1.3A_Generic) but the color of the text does not alternate between red and blue in my JSFiddle:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/JHpt9/

It can't be because I need jQuery or because of the markup, right? I copied it over exactly.

I also wanted to ask for clarification purposes: the reason var nIntervId; is defined as a global variable at the top is so that it can be used in both the changeColor() and stopTextColor() functions, right?

```
var nIntervId; //global variable

function changeColor() {
  nIntervId = setInterval(flashText, 500);
 }

function flashText() {
  var oElem = document.getElementById("my_box");
  oElem.style.color = oElem.style.color == "red" ? "blue" : "red";
}

function stopTextColor() {
  clearInterval(nIntervId);
}
```

In other words, if the code looked like this:

```
function changeColor() {
  var nIntervId = setInterval(flashText, 500);
}

function flashText() {
  var oElem = document.getElementById("my_box");
  oElem.style.color = oElem.style.color == "red" ? "blue" : "red";
}

function stopTextColor() {
  clearInterval(nIntervId); //undefined??
}
```

Comment: Quentin answered why your code didn't work, so I'll answer your second question; You are correct about the reason for `nItervId` being a gloabl variable. It's for the `clearInterval()`-method.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are defined inside another function (which is executed `onLoad`) (as per the second drop down menu in the JSFiddle options on the left).

This means they are scoped to that function and are not globals.

They are therefore out of scope for your `onload="stopTextColor();"` attribute.

Just call `stopTextColor()` in your existing onload handler and not in another one you create with the `onload` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle works fine. Just change the second drop down menu on the left which says **onLoad** to **No Wrap - in Head** option.

You should also have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036969/nowrap-condition-in-html-head-and-body) link to know **WHY**.