# why alert not working in js and index return -1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why alert not working in js and index return -1?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXvYK/)

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="menu-controls">
  <li>
    <a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(0);" id="menu-controls-0" href="#" class="">
      <span>
        Home
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(1);" id="menu-controls-1" href="#" class="">
      <span>
        Oleg Test
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a target="_self" onclick="return displaySubMenu(2);" id="menu-controls-2" href="#" class="act">
      <span>
        Products
      </span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Jquery Code :

```
function displaySubMenu(menuid) {

    var myActive = jQuery("a.act").parent().index();
    var myClicked = jQuery("#menu-controls-"+menuid).parent().index();

    alert(myActive+"==="+myClicked);

    if (myActive < myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active was left");
    } else if (myActive > myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active was right");
    } else if (myActive == myClicked) {
        alert("Previous active is this clicked one");
    }

    jQuery("a.act").removeClass("act");
    jQuery("#menu-controls-"+menuid).addClass("act");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine: [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXvYK/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xXvYK/3/ select `no-wrap in body` option while calling javascript function :) in fiddle options

Comment: i am getting the index as 2.can't get any -1 values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle works. Just select the **No Wrap - in (head)** option on the left side under *Frameworks & Extensions* section.

Comment: why this No Wrap - in (head) ?

Comment: "That simply means place your JavaScript between the <head> tags". See [REFERENCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036969/nowrap-condition-in-html-head-and-body).

Comment: And you are getting index 2 because the elements which you are selecting are placed at 3rd position i.e. index number 2.