# How to get a text editor (Notepad++) to execute like 'No wrap- in <head>' in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

i understand this might be a  weird question but i cant think of any other way to word it/ask it.

i have copied all my code character for character into the below jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3vqj9z6o/

on the left hand side there is an option for when/how you want the js to load. when i select `onload` it does not work but if i select `No wrap- in <head>` then it does work.  i was wondering how you get it to simulate this in the text editor because currently it is behaving the same way as the `onload` scenario. furthermore i have tried copying my javascript function into `<script></script>` tags but it is not playing ball this way either. this was working yesterday but now is failing. any ideas?
thanks

Comment: By wrapping your js in `script` tags and placing it within your `head` tags

Comment: In the **fiddle** using `onload` your code is rendered as `window.onload=function(){ function changeNavbarColor(ids){...}` so is not going to work as the function is never in scope.  What exactly are you doing with NPP?

Comment: Like @Johan said. Just place it inside your `head`. [See this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036969/nowrap-condition-in-html-head-and-body)

Comment: @Johan as stated i have already placed my code inside `<script>` tags and i have put it inside the html `<head>` tags

Comment: if i have put my code, that you can see in the jsfiddle, then why would it not work if i have followed the correct procedures in my text editor?